# How to fill group table with nine set members rather than eight.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

For the binary operation on $S=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$ defined by table, assume associativity and investigate all other properties.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
° &a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h\\
\hline
a &a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h\\
\hline
b &b&c&d&a&h&g&e&f\\
\hline
c &c&d&a&b&f&e&h&g\\
\hline
d &d&a&b&c&g&h&f&e\\
\hline
e &e&g&f&h&a&c&b&d\\
\hline
f &f&h&e&g&c&a&d&b\\
\hline
g &g&f&h&e&d&b&a&c\\
\hline
h &h&e&g&f&b&d&c&a\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Associativity is assumed.
Closure is there.
Identity is given by $a$. 
Latin square property is followed, i.e. unique map for $x.y$, with given elements $x,y \in\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$. Hence a group. Considered the Latin square property at the end, though it is redundant once associativity property holds; as quasi-groups lack the associativity property. Also, holding Latin square property is not sufficient, as that is sufficient for quasi-groups, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1350756/424260), and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Epadraic/mathcamp_2012/latin_squares/MC2012_LatinSquares_lecture3.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjZyauK0Jr4AhX0UGwGHZ7GAs0QFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0iUomQNgny8Yh08kuTPIql).

show that above shown is a binary operation on the subsets $$S_0=\{a\}, S_1=\{a,c\}, 
S_2=\{a,e\},$$ $$S_3=\{a,f\}, S_4=\{a,g\},$$ $$S_5=\{a,h\}, S_6=\{a,b,c,d\},$$ $$S_7=\{a,c,e,f\}, S_8=\{a,c,g,h\}$$ but not on the subsets $T_1=\{a,b\}$ and $T_2=\{a,f,g\}$ of $S$.

But, this is a nine-member Set, unlike eight earlier. Also, am unable to understanding the binary operation exactly. If simply take the corresponding entries as above for eight elements, then table is below with no entry for ninth element in the set. It doesn't even make sense as last element is not in the table at all, in the filled part. But, what sort of operation it is.

Further, how to handle the next problem with two members only $T_1, T_2$?

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
° &S_0&S_1&S_2&S_3&S_4&S_5&S_6&S_7&S_8
\\
\hline
S_0&S_0&S_1&S_2&S_3&S_4&S_5&S_6&S_7&S_8
\\
\hline
S_1&S_1&S_2&S_3&S_0&S_7&S_6&S4&S_5&\\
\hline
S_2&S_2&S_1&S_2&S_3&S_4&S_5&S_6&S_7&\\
\hline
S_3&S_3&S_0&S_1&S_2&S_6&S_7&S_5&S_4&\\
\hline
S_4&S_4&S_6&S_5&S_7&S_0&S_2&S_1&S_3&\\
\hline
S_5&S_5&S_7&S_4&S_6&S_2&S_0&S_3&S_1&\\
\hline
S_6&S_6&S_5&S_7&S_4&S_3&S_1&S_0&S_2&\\
\hline
S_7&S_7&S_4&S_6&S_5&S_1&S_3&S_2&S_0&\\
\hline
S_8&S_8&&&&&&&&
\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The image is here for the problem source.
[image]

*Edit* Consequent to @CyclotomicField
have read here (https://www.oglop.com/group_theory/ch_2/section2_subgroup_criterion) that for finite fields (which above is), the Subgroup criterion is: if $x,y\in H$ then $xy \in H$.

So, for $$S_0=\{a\}, \text{it is obvious}$$ $$S_1=\{a,c\}, 
S_2=\{a,e\},\text{it is obvious}$$ $$S_3=\{a,f\}, \text{it is obvious},$$

$$S_4=\{a,g\},\text{it is obvious},$$ $$S_5=\{a,h\}, \,\,
\text{it is obvious},$$
$$S_6=\{a,b,c,d\},\,\, a  \circ 
 b/c/d \,\, \text{or}\,\, b/c/d \circ a \,\, \text{is obvious},$$ $$ b \circ
c = d, b\circ d= a, c\circ b= d, c\circ d= b, d\circ b= a, d\circ c= b$$

$$S_7=\{a,c,e,f\}, c\circ e= f, c\circ f= e, e\circ f= c, e\circ c= f, f\circ c= e, f\circ e= c$$ $$ S_8=\{a,c,g,h\}, \,
c\circ g= h, c\circ h= g, g\circ c= h, g\circ h= c, h\circ c= g, h\circ g= c$$

Now, need show that subsets $T_1=\{a,b\}$ and $T_2=\{a,f,g\}$ of $S$ are not subgroups.
$T_1=\{a,b,c\},$ so  <strike>(obviously)</strike>
not holds under the given operation.

$T_2=\{a,f,g\}, f\circ g= d, g\circ f= b.$
So, fails here.

<strike>(So, is the question  about the individual subsets? I think it is for a different cause, say between subsets, if hold the operation: say, $T_1 \circ T_2 \not \in T_1,  T_2$.</strike>

Please tell if correct or not?

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\circ &\{a,b\}&\{a,f,g\} 
\\
\hline
\{a,b\} & \{a,b\} & \{a,f,e,g\} 
\\
\hline
\{a,f,g\} & \{a,h,f\} &\{a,f,d,b\} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Interestingly, all $S_i, S_j,\,\, i,j \in \{0,1,\cdots, 8\}$ are closed wrt operation $\circ$ under $S_i\circ S_j$.)

Comment: I'm not sure you're on the right track. I would expect you to say that $a^2 \in S_1$, $e^2 \in S_1$ and $ae = ea \in S_1$, so the binary operation applies to that subset. I would expect you to examine the products in $T_1$ to find pairs that violate closure.

Comment: @CyclotomicField If you mean by $S_1=\{a,c\}$, need consider the subgroup with identity element $a=e$, then these are all subgroups to be checked for following group axioms except associative property is inherited, identity is there in each subgroup, so need check If inverse lies in the subgroup, and closure too. So, need do this individually for each subgroup? Is there any coherent way like group table to show subgroups all in a go? Seems a silly question, but wished if there were a simple way to list subgroup properties for all subgroups of a group!

Comment: Yes do it for each subset and you're showing that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not subgroups unlike the $S_k$. As you said, closure is the only property you need to check beyond inverses. The Subgroup criterion can be useful here, which is that if $x,y \in H$ then $xy^{-1} \in H$. For sets this small inspection is probably faster.

Comment: @CyclotomicField have read here (https://www.oglop.com/group_theory/ch_2/section2_subgroup_criterion) that for finite fields (which above is), the Subgroup criterion is: if $x,y\in H$ then $xy \in H$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField please see the edit, where $T_1$ is obviously following the subgroup property, while $T_2$ is not. So, is the question  about the individual subsets? I think it is for a different cause, say between subsets, if hold the operation: say, $T_1 \circ T_2 \not \in T_1,  T_2$.

Comment: Is $T_1$ closed under the operation? When you multiply an element of $T_1$ by an element of $T_1$, do you always get an element of $T_1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson edited, but still feel the striked out part is intended by question. Though, if $T_1\circ T_1\not \in T_1$, then no need to continue.

Comment: $T_1$ is not closed. Did you forget to check $b^2$? Also, why are you using the sets rather than the elements of the set? The operation is defined over the elements, not the sets. $T_1 \circ T_1$ doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: How can you write $T_1=\{\,a,b\,\}$, jiten, and then write $T_1=\{\,a,b,c\,\}$?

Comment: Are you still there, jiten?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. Also, please cite your sources.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.